# Docker compose error on creating container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run two containers using the docker compose.But i am getting error when  i run. Could not figure out the issue as i am trying for the first time.I have attached the file as well from where i am running docker-compose.
[image: log of docker-compose up]

[image: docker ps -al]

My docker-compose file is here.
[file_to_create_container](https://mnsu-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/tu9419io_campus_mnsu_edu/Et3QJSqGBlNHik3t-eBx1MIBmNVYQK6f-Jn6kX6fbee-dQ?e=de2MwG)

New error::
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Dockerfile, you can try to change the last line from `CMD ["python", "producer.py"]` to `CMD ["python", "/code/producer.py"]`.

**Update:**

I did some testing with your code. The problem is not with your Dockerfile, but your docker-compose.yml. The build context in it is incorrect. So you don't need to change Dockerfile. If you've already changed as suggested the above, change it back to `CMD ["python", "producer.py"]`.

You need to update your docker-compose.yml. The following works in my environment.

```
version: '2'

services: 
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.6.9-management-alpine
    ports:
      - "4369:4369"
      - "5671:5671"
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15671:15671"
      - "15672:15672"
      - "25672:25672"
    environment: 
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=guest
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=guest
    networks:
      - sky-net

  rabbitmq-producer:
    build:
      context: ./producer

    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
    links:
      - rabbitmq
    networks:
      - sky-net

networks:
  sky-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: I ran with change and it took me litter further but now  the  procedure.py is found in one place and down the way it says can't find /code/procedure.py   screenshot attached as new error

Comment: I will try it on my side and will let you know.

Comment: Thank You Chun Liu. Appreciate your help.